# Buttons to stage and discard selections in Rstudio editor not working

Tags: r, git, rstudio

I have a problem that I am unable to use the "Stage line/selection" and "Discard line/selection" buttons that appear when selecting specific lines in the Rstudio git review changes. When pressed, the selection disappears and nothing happens.

To illustrate, say I have a file in which I have made some additions and deletions:

---

[image: Nothing selected]

---

Note, the "Stage chunk" and "Discard chunk" buttons on the right works as expected.

Now, say I wish to stage and commit only the added lines (the code comment). I first select the lines:

---

[image: Addition selected]

---

However, selecting either of the buttons, the first line of the selection is kept and nothing is staged:

---

[image: Result]

---

Again, nothing happens if "stage chunk" or "discard chunk" is pressed for the single line selection that remains.

The problem seems to be a bit intermittent.  My experience is, that it often happens if I have made many and "complex" changes. Editing a few lines does not cause the problem. From searching, I've only found suggestions to avoid spaces in filenames (which I do not have).

**Edit, May 2020**
Now appears as an issue at GitHub:

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/5476

Comment: I've had the same problem off and on for a couple of years. Any solutions?

Comment: @ChrisMerkord Nope, no solution. I still have the issue with Rstudio Version 1.1.463.

Comment: There is a bug issued about this problem: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/5476

Comment: @JaBe Thanks --- I asked the question Nov 2018. Nothing was to be found back then. But I'll provide your link in the post.

Comment: @JaBe your link was extremely helpful.  The bug details on github provide a simple workaround (as stated in the bug title).  I have just tried, and can confirm that if Context is changed from the default (?) of "10 line" to "All lines", then discarding individual lines and multiple line selections works as expected, both for additions and deletions.